# VPN connection is open. But can't ping internal network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have run into a problem with my VPN.

At home i have set up a test lab. I Have a server running VMware ESXi and vCenter server, so in my internal network i connect to the vCenter server to manage the ESXi host. I looked up the ports vSphere uses and forwarded them. From a external network i can log into my vCenter server but if i try to open a console it says cant connect MKS on 192.168.1.151:902. But i already forwarded port 902 to the vCenter server on 192.168.1.150.

As a solution i thought of VPN so i add a role to my AD server, in the role network en routing i setup VPN and i could connect to it with my laptop.

The Problems:
I can connect to my VPN by PPTP but i cant ping into my internal network (say ping 192.168.1.150 (vCenter server) i get a timed out.

What i tried:
First i saw that my ip address set by PPP did not have a gateway and subnet but did have a valid IP address in the right range. So i set the values manually but no success. 
Then i tried turning off all firewalls (on the servers and my laptop) but no success.
Then i set a check on send al traffic through VPN on my MacBook no success.
I checked the permissions on the server and it seems ok (i'm Administrator).
Last i searched this forum and tried a bunch of possible solutions but no success

So i hope i explained my problem correctly so you guys can help me.

I'm a student and I know i can only ask professional questions on this forum but i hope you can help me so i can learn from this experience.

Thanks,

Comment: This will likely be closed because it is a home network, and like you stated, is not a professional environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting - `cant connect MKS on 192.168.1.151:902.` is most probably a dns issue - caused due the the ESXi host being added in the vCenter using a host name or fqdn. In your client computer, edit the `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file and add the hostname and IP address of your esxi server. For instance,

```
192.168.1.50    esxihost
192.168.1.50   esxihost.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just sharing general steps which you can follow to check here.

Once you connect to vpn server, you get local ip address (vpn address) from the vpn server, now you are part of local network (still you do not have complete access of local, it then depend on the access policies created on vpn/firewall).

After connecting, if you are unable to access internal resource then make sure that ports / access rules are allowed on the vpn server (consider vpn server rules as well any other firewall running on the server. Not know how you can check in windows).

If you are sure and confirm that port / access are open then you need to run some sniffer on vpn server or the destination machine to check if your packets are reaching till the server or not. If it get stuck before destination server then you would need to check on vpn server (mostly). If it's getting reach till destination server then check, returns packets is routing via same path or not. Check gateway on destination machine.

Note:- Some time due to bad routing on vpn client machine also this kind of issue happens, make sure all this setting are proper.